# Platform Encryption not appearing in Sandbox?

Tags: apex

I  need to setup "Platform Encryption" for the some fields. So I am reading from this document http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_pe_enable_files_attachments.htm&language=en__1 here it is saying that

> "Available in: Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions.
>   Available in Developer Edition at no charge for organizations created
>   in Summer ’15 and later"

So my org have "**Unlimited Editions**". so it should appear but it is not appearing

What is the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Platform encryption is available in all editions. In developer edition it is available at free of cost.

For Unlimited edition, (sandbox or prod.) you will have to pay additional fees to enable this feature.

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide me an official document for it?

Comment: @RavikantKedia contact salesforce support at L3, you will get to know. There is no official documentation publicly available regarding this. This is a paid feature. Prices are not public.

Comment: can you give me a link for Salesforce support l3. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Or any other link where you readout this?

Comment: @RavikantKedia here is an official document that says "Available as add-on subscription in: Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions. Available in Developer Edition at no charge for organizations created in Summer ’15 and later.
Available in Salesforce Classic."

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_pe_overview.htm

Answer (score 1):

That confused me as well.

To clarify Ashwani's response - you need to contact Salesforce to get this feature switched on (and pay them a hefty sum of cash).

I agree though - the documentation is confusing. I spent time trying to find out how to switch this on as well.

Comment: Any link where you readout this?

Comment: I haven't actually seen it documented anywhere that you need to contact Salesforce, but one of my colleagues implemented it for a customer and had to contact Salesforce directly to get it switched on.